# Konkurrenz durch or mit?

Tags: preposition

I encountered a phrase *Konkurrenz durch Privatsender* (in a passage talking about radios).

In my dictionary, *Konkurrenz* usually comes with *mit* (no example with *durch*). Is it common to use *durch* here? Is there any difference between *Konkurrenz durch* and *Konkurrenz mit*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to find this kind of information is the DWDS usage database. From what I found, *Konkurrenz mit* translates as "competition with" while *Konkurrenz durch* translates as "competition from". The difference is subtle, but the English phrases seem to correspond well with the German ones. Specifically, use *mit*/"with" when you want to stress that there are several entities all striving for the same goal. Use *durch*/"from" when you're comparing competition to an outside force that makes life difficult for a particular entity.

In general, you should probably include at least a full sentence example for context. It wasn't a problem this time but it might help for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your snippets are a bit small to judge. Typically the preposition is mandated by the used verb and can't be chosen independently. As a rough rule, *durch* is used when the passive part is referred to, the party receiving new competition:

> Tageszeitungen leiden unter der Konkurrenz durch Lokalradios.

*Mit* or *zu* (I would prefer the latter) start from the active part, the newly arriving competition and refer to existing competitors:

> Chinesische Autokonzerne treten bei Autos mit Elektroantrieb in Konkurrenz zu/mit europäischen Herstellern.